# Passing Target Group Target as Parameters Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup` that accepts Target as parameters as template below :

```
FETargetGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup'
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub 'targetgroup-ccp-fe-${EnvironmentName}'
      Port: 443
      Protocol: HTTPS
      TargetType: ip
      Targets: 
        - Id: !Select[0,!Split [",", !Ref TargetGroupIPs]]
        - Id: !Select[1,!Split [",", !Ref TargetGroupIPs]]
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
```

And the Parameter :

```
  TargetGroupIPs:
   Description: IPs to be included in Target Group
   Type: String
```

The problem here this is static to 2 IPs, I want it to accept x number of IPs. Ex :

```
FETargetGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup'
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub 'targetgroup-ccp-fe-${EnvironmentName}'
      Port: 443
      Protocol: HTTPS
      TargetType: ip
      Targets: !Split [",", !Ref TargetGroupIPs]
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
```

But I Get validation error: **Target accepts List of Objects**. How it can be done correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How it can be done correctly ?

It **can't be done in plain** CloudFormation (CFN). This would require a looping mechanism which does not exist in CFN.

To overcome this, you would have to either create CFN [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) or [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html). In both cases you would have to write a **lambda function**. The difference is that the function for macro would parse your original template (or fragment of it) and construct dynamically the `Targets`. In contrast, the function for the custom resource would fully create the target groups using AWS SDK taking your `TargetGroupIPs` as its input parameter.